# How does the BIOS initialize the screen?

Tags: assembly, bios, firmware

how does the BIOS Initialize the Screen? I'm looking for an answer I've been searching through the web but, can't find something... but, I've found a website! but, it says [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/feng/cos/resources/BIOS/) that the is initialized to address C000h. is the video card really hard wired to the memory address C000h? please enlighten me and TY in advance... :D

Comment: It’s not “hardwired”, although the primary video card is *mapped* in such systems - http://xwindow.angelfire.com/page13_1.html

Comment: Also related: https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware.  Although in modern machines, probably a lot of the VGA I/O port interface is actually emulated, even if the text-mode framebuffer is still real RAM when the firmware puts the modern video hardware into that mode during bootup.

Comment: The BIOS functions were there so that we didnt need to know the specific details of how the video card worked (or other peripherals) it was a common set of calls and the vendor would supply the bios code for their card that handled those calls and performed whatever actions on their card to make that happen.  The main motherboard BIOS/bootloader would detect these peripheral bioses and map them into the interrupt table so that we only needed to make bios calls to do basic display and disk and other operations.

Comment: thanks! i'll search for some documentation about the card!

Comment: Video in particular was at a known address space and would expose the bios there so yes hardcoded.  Later peripherals like sound and ethernet would compete for space and resources (dma, interrupt, I/O and memory), some had detection schemes to allow them to land in different places, others jumpers, some simply hardcoded.  PCI was gross overkill but it came about in part to overcome these often hardcoded conflicts among vendors (not video)

Comment: On an IBM PC AT, the video card is initialised [here](https://github.com/kaneton/appendix-bios/blob/fa52ed6c6e197b79bcbfc865b9555aabf55adc82/src/test1.asm#L1997).  This code checks if your card is an MDA or CGA card and then calls `INT 10h` to set up a default video mode.  It also seems to do a quick test of the video memory.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE SOURCE CODE!!! :DDDD

Comment: @RonTech Note that this code is largely a red herring; if you have a VGA card, the real initialisation happens there.

Comment: yeah, definitely I might need some time to understand the large codebase...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is the video card really hard wired to the memory address C000h?

You are talking about the video BIOS, not about the screen memory?

In early IBM computers (like the "PC", the "XT" or the "AT"), the 128K addresses range from `C000h:0h` to `D000h:FFFFh` (this is the linear address range `C0000h` to `DFFFFh`) was intended for the firmware (BIOS) of add-on cards which were not supported by the "on-board" BIOS.

The first 32K (`C0000h` to `C7FFFh`) of this address range were reserved for video cards that were not supported by the on-board BIOS; the remaining 96K could be used by other types of cards (such as SCSI hard-disk controllers or network cards supporting booting from the network).

> How does the BIOS Initialize the Screen?

For computers with an on-board video card, this is done by the BIOS itself. In the technical reference manual of the "IBM PCjr" (a computer sold in 1983), you'll find the source code of such a BIOS.

When the BIOS starts up the computer, it is searching for add-on cards which have a firmware in the 128K address range mentioned above.

It detects the firmware of the video card and runs this firmware.

The reason why a video card has an own firmware is simple:

Especially for video cards providing more than VGA (16 colors at 640x480 pixels and 256 colors at 320x200 pixels) the initialization sequence is depending from manufacturer to manufacturer.

So for modern computers you cannot answer the "generic" question: "*How does the BIOS initialize the screen?*", but you could only answer the question how this is done for a certain manufacturer.

However, I suspect that most video cards' firmwares would put the card into a state where the card behaves like a VGA card, put the card into BIOS video mode 3 (80x25 text), fill the video memory with space characters (so the screen is empty) and put the text cursor to the top left corner.

Comment: The original PC had the bios listing in the technical reference manual, the PC jr came later (it perhaps had it as well, the original certainly did).  I dont know if I have it laying around here, I want to say there was a schematic in it too.

Comment: Yes, here it is, it does have the schematic as well.

Comment: @old_timer I didn't mention the PC reference manual because I was writing about PCs with an on-board video card. Most early PCs didn't have the video card on-board; but you could chose between CGA, MDA (and later EGA). The PCjr is one of the few early machines with on-board graphics.

Comment: Just for the record, the screen memory (framebuffer) is at 0xb8000 for text mode.  A legacy BIOS MBR will always(?) be started with the VGA hardware set up this way.